# How can I match a string with parenthesis in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, pattern-matching

This seems like it should be easy and straight-forward but I can't solve this for the life of me.

Using jQuery, I want to match a string with its parentheses using Regex.

This is the string I'm trying to match: `(CA)`

This is my Regex: `(/\(([A-Z]{2})\)/)`

I've tried using `new RegExp("\\(([A-Z]{2})\\)")` as well.

No matter what I try I always end up with the `Unrecognized expression: (CA)` error message in my console.

What am I doing wrong? Any advice would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

**EDIT Aug. 4 @ 9:09 GMT-7**

Here is my full code:

`<div class="athlete-name">Random Joe</div>
 <div class="high-school">Jonah Lomu Senior (CA)</div>`

Upon successful match, the `(CA)` will be replaced with `<img src="/img/flag/ca.svg"/>`

Comment: Can you provide a full example of your code. Also, Are you trying to match including or excluding the brackets?

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: Why do you use double parens in Regex (before and after escaped one)?

Comment: @hindmost Because with jQuery, if you're going to use the meta characters as a literal part of the code, they have to be escaped with \\ preceding them. See here: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 1):

[This is the regex that you want to match the string.](https://regex101.com/r/fE8oM7/2)

```
(\([A-Z]{2}\))
```

[Here's how it would work.](https://jsfiddle.net/ocexhvc8/2/)

```
var s = "(CA)";
var r = /(\([A-Z]{2}\))/;

if(r.test(s)){
    alert('Matched!');
}
```

[Give your edit, here's how it might be used.](https://jsfiddle.net/wd26t16p/1/)

```
$('div').each(function() {
    var s = $(this).html();
    var r = s.replace(/(\([A-Z]{2}\))/, '<img src="/img/flag/ca.svg"/>');  
    $(this).html(r);
});
```

Comment: It gives me this in the console: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of undefined`

Comment: I deleted my answer and upvoted yours as this really isn't a regex question and you seem to have a handle on this.

Comment: Any idea how to get around the `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: (CA)` error message? That's currently what's holding me up.

Comment: @DaveyJake You need to post your javascript code as well, and possibly the line number that you're getting the error on.